# Laravel 5.2: how create image file from json

Tags: laravel

In my controller i receive from form data like this:

```
"output":{"width":500,"height":500,"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQFAH/9k=..."},"actions":{"crop":{"x":97,"y":0,"height":500,"width":500},"size":null}}[
```

Can I create image file from this data?

upd 1.
Decode the json - ok, pull out the image data - ok, decode the base64 - ok, but when I try write to disk then I got error: NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 96: Unable to init from given binary data.

```
$file = Request::input('photo');
$imagedata=json_decode($file);
$file=$imagedata->output->image;
$image = base64_decode($file);

$png_url = "user-".time().".png";
$path = "/public/".$png_url;

Image::make($image)->save($path);
```

upd 2.
**Solved with file_put_contents function.**

Comment: decode the json, pull out the image data, decode the base64, write to disk.

Comment: Thank you Marc, I get an error when trying to make the image::make. First post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

```
$file = Request::input('photo');
$imagedata=json_decode($file);
$file=$imagedata->output->image;
$png_url = "user-".time().".png";
$path = "uploads/".$png_url;
$image = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $file));
file_put_contents($path, $image);
```

Answer (score 2):

here is how you can save image from a json data:

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
    . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
    . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
    . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    echo imagejpeg($im , base_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "sth.jpeg") ;
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Salar, but I get an error: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format.

Comment: the base64 is ALREADY  a jpeg image. it just needs to be decoded/saved. running it through GD and recompressing to jpeg will just trash the image quality

Comment: @Alex then alex you have problem in encoding your images. take a sample image, and try to encode it with online tools, then compare the result with data sent from your client and make sure you have no problem.

Comment: @Salar thank you for your help, but we don't need use imagecreatefromstring function in this situation. Problem solved with file_put_contents function.